# PDO could not find driver Google App engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, pdo

google app engine website clearly states that this feature is already available to use, but when I try using it, I get this error. Any ideas?

error message: could not find driver

php file for reference

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:8080';
$dbname = '*********'; #edited out
$dbuser = '****'; #edited out
$dbpass = '******'; #edited out

phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

try{
$dbh = new pdo('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

echo 'safe1';

foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * FROM eastInfo') as $row){
print_r($row);
}#end for
$dbh = null;
}catch(PDOException $e){
print "error!: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />";
die();
}#end try catch
?>
```

I am using Ubuntu Linux

Comment: When I check the phpinfo(), it states PDO enabled only for sqlite.

Comment: Please provide error message. Hint: you can edit your question.

Comment: The host string should be set up correctly according to this page. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Connect_to_your_database

Comment: are you using local PHP, or are you using App Engine's dev_appserver?

Comment: I was using local PHP

Answer (score 1):

try to use

mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name;dbname=your-db-name

instead for appengine and leave the password blank as it's not needed for local connections from user root.

Greets